# SFML - Frame independent movement + dragging window

Tags: windows, frame, drag, sfml

I am trying to implement frame independent movement in SFML, but am having trouble getting it to work. When I had this problem earlier with SDL, I found somewhere that Windows pauses the main thread of an application whenever it is moved (by dragging the title-bar). The problem comes because when the window is being dragged, the clock updates but the movement is not drawn until I let go of the window. When I move the window, the window is no longer being drawn to, but the time is still increasing. Thus, when I let go of the window, the units immediately jump to where they would be if the window had not been dragged.

I tried thinking of a solution, and since Windows only pauses the main thread, I considered just running the entire game in a separate thread, and launching it in main() but that does not appear to work as the same result occurs. I also thought about the extremely low FPS's I get as a result, but I would have no way of being able to differentiate between someone dragging the window and if their game is just naturally running slowly... There has to be a way to either prevent windows from pausing the main thread, or doing something that prevents this issue, but I haven't found any sort of solution on the internet...

Here is a link to a zip file which demonstrates the problem. Both Demo0 and Demo1 are the same, except Demo1 uses a second thread to run the program, yet the same effect occurs. Just run both and watch as the delta value is output to command line. Then drag the window and move it to some other part of the screen. When you let go, you should see a very large delta value and the circle should jump ahead depending on how long you had the window suspended. The source code is all there (in the "src" folder), so I hope people can understand the exact problem: http://www.sendspace.com/file/4er8f4

Comment: If you can upload an app which demonstrates the problem, I will try to help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I see two solutions to the problem:

You can try to see if the sf::Events LostFocus or Resized picks up a window drag, and if they do, simply pause the clock on the game.  More information can be found here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php

However, if that doesn't work, I would simply add an upper-cap on your delta.  Meaning, if the game goes above a certain threshold of delta (1/60 or 1/30), you set delta to a lower value.  In your situation though, this cap could probably be really big, like 1/15.

```
if(delta > 1/15.0f)
    delta = 1/15.0f;
```

Chances are you don't expect your game to be playable at 15fps anyways, and if the user drags the window while moving, the worst you'll have to deal with is a 15fps delta on resume.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already had tested LostFocus, and it does not inform. I will try Resize, but I will be surprised if it works. Your solution works to some extent, but if the user drags the window only a small amount, then there will still be a delay. If I can't find a better solution, then I will go with this. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it... sf::Event::Resized is not triggered when the window is dragged.